# Outlook Add-in differentiate between "new event" or "edit event"

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Does anyone know if it is possible to capture the type of event that a calendar booking is in from an Add-in object, see image?
[1. This form is a new booking "New event"
2. This is an old booking, opened for editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYGn2.png)

I would like the add-in to respond different depending on which type hence the question :)
var isEvent = newEvent or editedEvent

I have only been able to fetch - Invited persons - Date and time - Room name, but I don't know how i'm supposed to get type event.

Answer (score 0):

To recognize whether you deal with a saved previously item or brand new one you may try retrieving the `ID` value by using the [getItemIdAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-appointmentcompose-getitemidasync-member(2)) method which asynchronously gets the ID of an item (if it is saved). When invoked, this method returns the item ID via the callback function. A new item ID is blank or empty string.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Eugene Astafiev. 
As correctly mentioned above providing event type is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Provided workaround to use getItemIdAsync can be utilized which gives ItemId in case an appointment in compose mode has been saved as draft or sent previously and returns an error if item is not yet saved.